# CSS 3 row, first row fixed size, last row fixed size, center take rest

Tags: html, css, user-interface

i want to put 3 row 
1- the first  has fixed height
2- second has flexible take the rest size  but  the issue  is third row because it finds  in some case  and i want second take size the rest size in all cases 
3- third if founded take fixed height

[image]

FYI :  container Row has fixed height

```
.container
{
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row-1
{
  height: 50px;
}

.row-2
{
}

.row-3
{
  height: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: .container
{
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.firstRow
{
  height: 50px; 
}

.secondRow
{ 
}

.thirdRow
{
  height:50px; 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with using flex, it can be achieved like this :

```css
.container
{
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.firstRow
{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.secondRow
{
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.thirdRow
{
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstRow"></div>
  <div class="secondRow"></div>
  <div class="thirdRow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks 
it's worked after add your code and add { overflow: hidden;} to secondRow

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
}
article {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
header {
    background: deeppink;
    padding: 1rem;
    height:25px;
}
main {
    background: whitesmoke;
    color: #444;
    padding: 1rem;
}
footer {
    background: purple;
    padding: 1rem;
    height:40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <article>
    <header>
        Page Header
    </header>
    <main>
        Hi, there's not much content, yet. You can write in here to expand the container.
    </main>
    <footer>
        All rights reversed.
        <br>
        <small>I am always at the bottom of the page</small>
    </footer>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position: fixed` and add the `padding in main section for header and footer`

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
}
article {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
header {
    background: deeppink;
    padding:1rem;
    height:25px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
main {
        background: whitesmoke;
    color: #444;
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 64px;
    padding-bottom: 93px;
}
footer {
    background: purple;
    padding: 1rem;
    height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <article>
    <header>
        Page Header
    </header>
    <main>
        Hi, there's not much content, yet. You can write in here to expand the container.
    </main>
    <footer>
        All rights reversed.
        <br>
        <small>I am always at the bottom of the page</small>
    </footer>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```